# Simulation Poisson Process using R and ggplot2

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo, poisson

Using a simulation of a Poisson process with rate lambda = 0.7. Show a sample run of a Poisson process with N(t) on the vertical axis and time t on the horizontal axis. The simulation is from the range t[0:100]. Generate first graph with 10 trajectories and second graph with 100 trajectories.

I have tried the following code but I cannot generate both graphs.

```
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

Process_poisson<- function(t, lambda){
distr_poisson<- rpois(1, t*lambda)
s_poisson<- sort(runif(distr_poisson, 0, t))
data.frame(x = c(0, 0, s_poisson),y = c(0, 0:distr_poisson))
}

N_simulations<- function(n,t,lambda){
s_poisson<- lapply (1:n, function(n) data.frame(Process_poisson(t, lambda), simulation = n))
s_poisson<- ldply (s_poisson, data.frame)
s_poisson$simulation<- factor(s_poisson$simulation)
}

t<- 0:100
lambda<- 0.7
N_simulations(10, t, lambda)
N_simulations(100, t, lambda)

par(mfrow = c(1,2))

matplot(x, y, type = "l", lty = 0:5, lwd = 1, lend = par("lend"),
     pch = NULL, col = simulation, cex = 0.5, bg = NA, main =sprintf("Nº simulations of trajectories of Poisson Process",10,lambda), xlab = "Time", ylab = "N(t)",
   xlim = c(0,100), ylim = c(-10,0))

matplot(Proceso_poisson(t, lambda), n, y, type = "l", lty = 0:5, lwd = 1, lend = par("lend"),
     pch = NULL, col = simulacion, cex = 0.5, bg = NA, main =sprintf("Nº simulations of trajectories of Poisson Process",10,lambda), xlab = "Time", ylab = "N(t)",
     xlim = c(0,100), ylim = c(-10,0))
```

How could I do it?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Some simple stuff off the bat, in your first `matplot()` you use `x` and `y`, which are objects that you haven't defined. In the second `matplot()`, and this could be a typo, you use `Proceso_poisson()` when the function you actually defined is called `Process_poisson()`. Third, `N_simulations()` doesn't return anything, at the end of the function you'll need to add `return(s_poisson)`.

Comment: @OTStats brings up great points for the most part, and while I agree you *should* add `return(s_poisson)` to the end of the `N_simulations()` function, it isn't necessary; you are already implicitly returning `s_poisson`, but invisibly. OTStats, you can confirm this by looking at `str(N_simulations(100, t, lambda))`

Comment: @duckmayr that's a good point, thanks for mentioning that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could make this simpler. Here's a ggplot solution.

First, create a function that will simulate a Poisson process by taking samples drawn from an exponential distribution with the appropriate lambda. In this example I have used a `while` loop that starts with a vector `x` whose first element is 0. The function grows this vector by adding random samples until its sum reaches the target duration `tmax`. This is not the most efficient way to do it, but should make the example clearer.

When the target is reached, the function returns the cumulative sum of the vector, which represents the arrival times of a Poisson process of the appropriate lambda. Note that to make plotting easier, it actually returns a data frame with the cumulative times, the cumulative count, and a grouping variable `run` that will allow us to plot several runs easily on a single plot.

```
make_sample_df <- function(run, tmax, lambda)
{
  x <- 0
  while(sum(x) < tmax) x <- c(x, rexp(1, lambda))
  data.frame(t = cumsum(x), N = seq_along(x), run = rep(run, length(x)))
}
```

We can now use this function inside our actual plotting function:

```
plot_poisson <- function(runs, tmax, lambda)
{
  # Creates one data frame for each run, this sticks them all together:
  df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(seq(runs), make_sample_df, tmax, lambda))

  ggplot2::ggplot(df, aes(t, N, group = run)) + 
    geom_step(alpha = 0.25) + 
    labs( title = paste(runs, "runs of Poisson process with lambda", lambda)) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, tmax))
}
```

So you can do:

```
plot_poisson(runs = 10, tmax = 100, lambda = 0.7)
```

[image]

```
plot_poisson(runs = 100, tmax = 100, lambda = 0.7)
```

[image]